# Unable to install Tabula with Anaconda

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install Tabula for Python, as it seems it is the way of extracting tables from PDFs. However I am unable to install it.

I am using Anaconda and have followed the step on Tabula's Anaconda page (https://anaconda.org/auto/tabula) to attempt to install it:

```
conda install -c auto tabula
```

But I just get an error message:
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdtmX.png)

As far as I'm aware, I have added the "auto" channel so it should be able to install it. But I guess I must be missing something. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Windows and in the [link](https://anaconda.org/auto/tabula) you provide I just see Linux-64 and Linux-32 I think that installing Tabula with Conda can return errors.

Activate your Conda environment and install Tabula using pip:

```
pip3 install tabula-py
```

**Note**

As pointed out in a comment by chezou the conda-forge way of installing Tabula seems not the best way to go if you want to keep it updated:

> Conda package is supported by someone else and it seems not maintained
>   well.
>   As of Feb 24th, 2019, conda version is v1.1.1 while the latest
>   pypi package is 1.3.1.
>   I would recommend installing via pip.

Answer (score 7):

You could just try:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Conda package is supported by someone else and it seems not maintained well. As of Feb 24th, 2019, conda version is v1.1.1 while the latest pypi package is 1.3.1. I would recommend installing via pip.

Answer (score 0):

Conda sources are limited to packages available in the channels you have set up.  You will need to either:

1. Set up a channel in Conda that contains tabula.(I tried this with other pacages but couldn't figure out a working method.)
   https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html
2. Install tabula into your Anaconda environment from source.
   https://docs.python.org/2/install/
3. use pip to install tabula in Conda environment.(you will need to install pip first)
   https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429
   Then:

   If tabula is in pipy, this will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tabula-py

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
> conda install -c conda-forge tabula-py  conda install -c
> conda-forge/label/cf201901 tabula-py
```